# TSQL: Call a stored procedure from another stored procedure and read the result

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that, ending with a SELECT, returns a recordset. I can call it within anoher stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC procedure @param
```

How to get the returning recordset? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like your stored procedure should really be a view: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258253%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Comment: Why would you make this statement? Who knows what is going on in the stored proc in the form of updates etc...

Answer (score 38):

You can create a temp table and then use `INSERT INTO #MyTable EXEC procedure @param`.

There are some other [techniques listed here](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you can't.  What you probably want to do is use a function for your first (or both) procedures.  Functions can only return one thing, but they can return a table.  Stored procedures can return multiple results, but not to other functions/stored procedures.

e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetSubordinates] (
    @sPersonID VARCHAR(10),
    @nLevels INT
)
RETURNS @tblSubordinates TABLE
(
    Person_Id VARCHAR(10),
    Surname char(25),
    Firstname char(25)
)
AS
BEGIN
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, I would recommend returning a Table-Valued Parameter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Comment: I thought TVP represented an input-only construct...OP seems to want to return the output of the proc?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an output variable in the stored proc.  For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_HelloWorld   @MyReturnValue int OUT
AS
SELECT @MyReturnValue = 100
Return @MyReturnValue
```

To call this stored proc, do the following:

```
DECLARE @TestReturnVal int 

EXEC sp_HelloWorld @TestReturnVal output
SELECT @TestReturnVal
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you CANNOT **RETURN** a recordset by stored procedure. By return, a stored procedure can only return integers.

You mentioned `SELECT` statement, which is a DQL and just for display purpose.

The way you can do to work around this issue is that you can assign the recordset to a global temporary table which can also be accessed within the outer stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, this seems to work fine if the `EXEC`'ed sproc has only a simple `SELECT` in it (with `SET NOCOUNT ON`), but as soon as you add any other T-SQL statements (`IF`, `DECLARE` etc), then you get a null rowset. I can confirm this as the case in Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU19) (KB5023049) - 15.0.4298.1 (X64) (running in a Linux container).

However, the most consistent way is to declare a `VIEW` for the end result that you want to `SELECT` from, and `SELECT` from that `VIEW` instead.