# How do I use result of SELECT in one stored procedure in another srored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a stored procedure that computes several values and `SELECT`s them:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]
AS
   DECLARE @value1 int;
   DECLARE @value2 int;
   SET @value1 =...
   IF( @value1 IS NULL ) 
       RETURN 0;
   SET @value2 =...
   SELECT @value1 AS Value1, @value2 AS Value2;
RETURN 0;
```

I know I can turn that into a table function but I'd rather not do that because of `RETURN` in the middle - sometimes there's just nothing to return.

I want to call that stored procedure from another stored procedure and use the values retrieved by `SELECT` in the other procedure. How do I do that?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184325/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-another-stored-procedure

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039200/tsql-call-a-stored-procedure-from-another-stored-procedure-and-read-the-result

Comment: before covering old TSQL ground you should always check out this site http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: @Jodrell: Google is not really a helpful answer (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers why).

Comment: @Josien, I've read your links and found the latter most pertitnent. I'm deleting my google comment, although, it was an effective way of finding the duplicates here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a temptable and insert both values in there.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (value1 int, value2 int)

INSERT INTO #Temp (value1, value2)
EXEC [dbo].[MyProc]
```

If Value1 is NULL there will be no record in #Temp, and in this case you don't need the return 0.

But if it is not your goal, and you need return 0, then you should use the @value1 and @value2 as output parameters.

Comment: Can I control which column from the `SELECT` goes into which column of the table?

Comment: Yes, but only if the number of columns and the types are matching. Like INSERT INTO #Temp(value1, value2) and INSERT INTO #Temp(value2, value1) is also possible.But you can't write a select on you EXEC ... statement. The return order from the stored procedure is defined there.

Comment: This answer is very useful, I'll just add that a table variable can be used instead of a temptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can add output parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]
(
  @value1 int = null output,
  @value2 int = null output
)
AS

   SET @value1 =...
   IF( @value1 IS NULL ) 
       RETURN 0;
   SET @value2 =...
   SELECT @value1 = Value1, 
          @value2 = Value2;
RETURN 0;
```

and use it:

```
declare @v1 int, 
        @v2 int

exec MyProc @v1 out, @v2 out

select @v1, @v2
```

or if you need more values you can use temporary table

```
create table #tmp
(
  val1 int null,
  val2 int null 
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]   
AS

   SET @value1 =...
   IF( @value1 IS NULL ) 
       RETURN 0;
   SET @value2 =...

   insert into #tmp
   SELECT Value1, Value2
   from tab

RETURN 0;
```

and use it:

```
create table #tmp
(
  val1 int null,
  val2 int null 
)

exec MyProc 

select *
from #tmp

drop table #tmp
```

Comment: Would recommend changing the return 0 at the end of myproc to 1. You can then do (in the calling stored proc) `DECLARE @Exists bit; exec @Exists = MyProc; If @Exists... Else...` just allows checkin if value 1 was null without using a count on the temp and stuff

Comment: Yes of course, but I wanted to show how to take values, nothing else.